# Passenger with NginX not registered as service in Fedora

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, fedora

I am running Fedora 16 32bit and I installed passenger with nginx (option 1 during installation, everything was handled for me). Installation went ok, but nginx is not registered as service.

The only way I can run it is directly through `/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`. There is no possibility to run it via `/etc/init.d/nginx`

Is there any way how to register it as service?

Comment: https://github.com/johnantoni/nginx_init_script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service` with the content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nginx
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After that you can control it with:

```
sudo systemctl stop|start|restart nginx.service
```

or

```
sudo service nginx stop|start|restart
```

To enable nginx to start on boot you can run `sudo systemctl enable nginx.service`.

Comment: For forking services such as nginx it is recommended to include the `PIDFile=` option in your service file.  So the above example would include `PIDFile=/var/run/nginx.pid` after the `Type=forking` line.  For more information see: [http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.service.html](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/systemd.service.html)

Answer (score 0):

I made following "hack". Installed freshly compiled nginx with Passenger support, checked that it runs properly when launched from command line, then installed nginx with `sudo yum install nginx` (it was CentOS).

And finally, I searched for `*nginx*` files in `/etc` folder and replaced there `/usr/sbin/nginx` to `/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`. Then rebooted the machine and was able to start nginx with `sudo service nginx start`.

There is certainly a more elegant way to do this, but I am lazy to study how in each Linux distribution services are registered.

Also I replaced there the paths for

- `nginx.conf`
- `nginx.pid` (`${prog}.pid`) - otherwise it won't be able to stop nginx